# How do you refresh a table view once dismissing a View Controller after inserting values using SQLite3?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, tableview, swift5

I have a tableViewController that holds a list of activities. Theres a button that takes you to a new view controller, which allows you to create a new activity, that then gets inserted into the database when the save button is pressed, which also dismisses the view controller to take you back to the list of activities. I want the activities to refresh so that the new activity they just inserted will be added to the table. I have tried

```
nextViewController = ActivitiesViewController()

dismissVC(){
nextViewController.viewDidLoad() }
```

It currently takes you back to the correct table view, but the rows do not update. It isn't until the phone is restarted that the values update.
Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to override the method `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` in your ActivitiesViewController and call a function to update the data (just as you do in `viewDidLoad`).

```swift
class ActivitiesViewController: UITableViewController { // UITableViewController or whatever you're using

  // your stuffs
  // ...
  // ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // load datas
     tableView.reloadData()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     // load datas
     tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

To explain a bit further why you should do this; in your code snippet, you're creating a new instance of ActivitiesViewController that is not the one that is displayed on the screen. Even if you update it, it's not linked to the one that is displayed.